# VBA for matching Sheet 1 columns to Sheet 2 columns

Tags: vba, excel

[image: Please see how Macro doesn't show][image: Please see where I have added the code--Sheet 4 (aka Master Sheet) Module]Sheet 1 has columns A-T. Some columns of Sheet 1 have formulas and others have a dropdown list.
Sheet 2 has columns A-P. I want to be able to paste the Sheet 1 data in Sheet 2-- The data generated as a result of formulas and drop downs. Also in a way, that if I change anything in Sheet 1 it changes on the other sheet. I want to be able to do this for multiple columns.
The thing is that Sheet 1 and Sheet 2 columns are not true to each other. I mean Column A of Sheet 1 is Column C in Sheet 2 etc..

Right now, I have simply equaled the cells using formula on both sheets to make this work. I don't wish to continue it this way. Macro will be better.

Thank you! Please help.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Rng As Range, Rc As Range, R As Long
   Dim hC As String, Lr As Long
   Dim Ws2 As Worksheet

   On Error GoTo mExit

   Set Ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet 2")
   hC = "AO"

   Application.EnableEvents = False
   Set Rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Columns("A:T"))

   If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
      For Each Rc In Rng.Rows

        R = Rc.Row
        If Range(hC & R).HasFormula Then
            Lr = Ws2.Range(Range(hC & R).Formula).Row
        Else
            With Ws2
               Lr = .Range(hC & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
               Range(hC & R).Formula = "='" & .Name & "'!" & hC & Lr
            End With
        End If

        With Ws2
           .Range("B" & Lr).Value = Range("A" & R).Value
           .Range("C" & Lr).Value = Range("C" & R).Value
           .Range("D" & Lr).Value = Range("D" & R).Value
           .Range("E" & Lr).Value = Range("E" & R).Value
           .Range("F" & Lr).Value = Range("F" & R).Value
           .Range("G" & Lr).Value = Range("G" & R).Value
           .Range("H" & Lr).Value = Range("H" & R).Value
           .Range("I" & Lr).Value = Range("I" & R).Value
           .Range("J" & Lr).Value = Range("J" & R).Value
           .Range("K" & Lr).Value = Range("AH" & R).Value
           .Range("L" & Lr).Value = Range("K" & R).Value
           .Range("M" & Lr).Value = Range("L" & R).Value
           .Range("N" & Lr).Value = Range("M" & R).Value
           .Range("O" & Lr).Value = Range("N" & R).Value
           .Range("P" & Lr).Value = Range("AA" & R).Value
           .Range(hC & Lr).Value = "Related"

        End With

      Next
   End If

mExit:
   Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Edited Code (3_31_3017)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim Rng As Range, Rc As Range, R As Long
   Dim hC As String, Lr As Long
   Dim Ws2 As Worksheet

   On Error GoTo mExit

   Set Ws2 = Worksheets("Route_Sheet")
   hC = "AP"

   Application.EnableEvents = False
   Set Rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Columns("A:AL"))

   If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
      For Each Rc In Rng.Rows

        R = Rc.Row
        If Range(hC & R).HasFormula Then
            Lr = Ws2.Range(Range(hC & R).Formula).Row
        Else
            With Ws2
               Lr = .Range(hC & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
               Range(hC & R).Formula = "='" & .Name & "'!" & hC & Lr
            End With
        End If

        With Ws2
            .Range("B" & Lr).Value = Range("A" & R).Value
            .Range(.Cells(Lr, "C"), .Cells(Lr, "J")).Value = Range(Cells(R, "C"), Cells(R, "J")).Value
            .Range(.Cells(Lr, "L"), .Cells(Lr, "O")).Value = Range(Cells(R, "K"), Cells(R, "N")).Value
            .Range("K" & Lr).Value = Range("AH" & R).Value
            .Range("P" & Lr).Value = Range("AA" & R).Value
            .Range("Q" & Lr).Value = Range("U" & R).Value
            .Range(hC & Lr).Value = "Related"
            End With

      Next
   End If

mExit:
   Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a unique identifier for each row?  Could do an Index/Match on that unique identifier to specify the columns you need.  Hard to speculate further due to lack of information.

Comment: @tigeravatar No index match won't be possible. New data will be put into sheet everyday.

Comment: @Fadi any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need at least one thing to know that `row(x)` in `Sheet 1` is related to `row(y)` in `Sheet 2`. this can be done by adding unique identifier for each row as @tigeravatar mentioned or by adding one formula in unused column in `row(x)` in `Sheet 1` relating to `row(y)` in `Sheet 2`.

In `Sheet 1` Module add this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim Rng As Range, Rc As Range, R As Long
   Dim hC As String, Lr As Long
   Dim Ws2 As Worksheet

   On Error GoTo mExit

   Set Ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet 2")
   hC = "U" 'Change this to any unused column and You can hide it

   Application.EnableEvents = False
   Set Rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Columns("A:T"))

   If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
      For Each Rc In Rng.Rows

        R = Rc.Row
        If Range(hC & R).HasFormula Then
            Lr = Ws2.Range(Range(hC & R).Formula).Row
        Else
            With Ws2
               Lr = .Range(hC & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
               Range(hC & R).Formula = "='" & .Name & "'!" & hC & Lr
            End With
        End If

        With Ws2
           ' Add here all columns you need like :
           '=====================================
           .Range("C" & Lr).Value = Range("A" & R).Value
           .Range("A" & Lr).Value = Range("B" & R).Value
           '...etc
           '=====================================
           .Range(hC & Lr).Value = "Related"
        End With

      Next
   End If

mExit:    
   Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

**Edit:**
Right click on "Master" sheet tab and select `View Code` and paste this code in it:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim Rng As Range, Rc As Range, R As Long
   Dim hC As String, Lr As Long
   Dim Ws2 As Worksheet

   On Error GoTo mExit

   Set Ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet 2") 'Change "Sheet 2" to your target sheet name like "Route_Sheet" or "Lists"
   hC = "AO"

   Application.EnableEvents = False
   Set Rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Columns("A:AH"))

   If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
      For Each Rc In Rng.Rows

        R = Rc.Row
        If Range(hC & R).HasFormula Then
            Lr = Ws2.Range(Range(hC & R).Formula).Row
        Else
            With Ws2
               Lr = .Range(hC & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
               If Not (Lr = 1 And .Range(hC & Lr).Value = vbNullString) Then Lr = Lr + 1                              
               Range(hC & R).Formula = "='" & .Name & "'!" & hC & Lr
            End With
        End If

        With Ws2
            .Range("B" & Lr).Value = Range("A" & R).Value
            .Range(.Cells(Lr, "C"), .Cells(Lr, "J")).Value = Range(Cells(R, "C"), Cells(R, "J")).Value
            .Range(.Cells(Lr, "L"), .Cells(Lr, "O")).Value = Range(Cells(R, "K"), Cells(R, "N")).Value
            .Range("K" & Lr).Value = Range("AH" & R).Value
            .Range("P" & Lr).Value = Range("AA" & R).Value

            .Range(hC & Lr).Value = "Related"

        End With

      Next
   End If

mExit:
   Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This is a Worksheet Event that run automatically when user change any cell inside Columns("A:AH").

If you want to run it manually you can add new sub in `Module1`:

```
Sub Test()
 With sheets("Master").Range("A2:A50") ' change this range to all rows you need like "A5:A100"
  .Value = .Value
 End With
End Sub
```

Or:

```
Sub Test()
 With Sheets("Master")
  Application.Run .CodeName & ".Worksheet_Change", .Range("A1:A50") 'change this range to all rows you need like "A5:A100"
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't understand the unique identifier part. But in AO1  ( an unused column of Sheet 1) (Master Sheet), I have put Route_Sheet!AO3 . I have added the code to module under Sheet 4 (Master Sheet)

Comment: But the code is not recognized by workbook, and when I run macro, it shows no name. I am adding the modified code to my original question (please see). Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: @NabeelaVan, form the image that you add it seems that you put the code in `Module1` not in `Sheet4` module and I don't see any sheet with name `Sheet 2` . change `Sheet 2` in the code to your target sheet like `Route_Sheet` or `Lists`

Comment: Okay now I'm adding the code to View code for Sheet 4 (Master Sheet). But please see new image, the workbook is not recognizing the code like it does for other two codes in the same workbook. Also, I made one small change in my previous codes with the B column. Sorry about that. Thank you Fadi. Greatly appreciate your time and effort to help.

Comment: Yay, Fadi the code is working. I resaved and that helped. Thank you. But please see the column change for B that I made in my original code. How do I account for that change in this new code that you gave me? Thanks a ton!

Comment: Also, the rows are filling in Route_sheet from the 3rd and onwards. First two are totally blank. What would be the reason for that? Though all the data is copied. But that is a small issue I might just hide those two rows.

Comment: @NabeelaVan, yes it will start from the second (not 3rd) row if there is no data in the sheet  as the first row must have the header (columns name)

Comment: @NabeelaVan, I edited it to start from first row. Maybe you need to delete column "AO" in both sheets to delete the old formulas.

Comment: Thanks very much throughout this! 
I've a fear that any manual edit on Route Sheet 2 would cause the code to disrupt. For ex: Resizing the table?

Comment: Yes I think you're right. I will delete AO. How will this affect the code?

But do I put in same formula again in AO?

Comment: No, Just  run the `Sub Test()` in my answer to create the formulas again (run it only one time).

Comment: Sorry about this question. But if I am adding a column after T in Master sheet, why is it interrupting the code? :(

Comment: @NabeelaVan, when you insert new column before column `AO` this column will shift to right so now the column that contain the formulas is `AP`, the same thing happen if you delete a column, all columns after it will shift to left. before insert or delete columns you need to disable events then insert or delete columns then update the code to refer to new address (for example `hC = "AP"`) then enable events again.

Comment: Yes, I did that please see the edited code with date 3_31_2017. However, there are no changes on the route sheet when data is entered into the master. Not for any columns. I am trying though.

Comment: @NabeelaVan, make sure to enable events again `Application.EnableEvents = True`.

Comment: Thank you! It all worked out! You're a life saver :)